# is it bad practice to findViewById in onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

i'm working on a recyclerView implementation in Android. here is my Adapter's onBindViewHolder method:

```
// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    val textView = holder.textView.findViewById(R.id.simple_text) as TextView
    textView.text = myDataset[position]
}
```

so basically the MyViewHolder class has a View field called textView (which is actually a layout from my res/layout folder) and i access the TextView (which is a child of textView in the layout) using findViewById. is this bad practice? should we avoid calling findViewById in the onBindViewHolder function?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly valid, and not a bad practice. Although you may add some optimization by caching a local reference of the child views inside your **ViewHolder** class implementation for faster access, but is up to you and will depend on your design requirements.

**A side note:** I would rename your ViewHolder's **textView** field to something more meaningful as maybe **itemLayout** or something else, to make it more clear that is referring to an actual layout and not a TextView widget. As you see there is already a different answer from someone else who didn't fully read your question, and got confused believing your **textView** field refers to the ViewHolder's **itemView**.

Comment: thanks. i read somewhere that findViewById is an expensive operation so its bad practice to call it from the recyclerview's onBindViewHolder method. you're saying this is not the case?

Comment: also a second comment (which is what caused the confusion) in the official docs they have an example where they access a text view directly from the layout file using R.layout.my_text_view and then cast it to textview (they don't show the xml so actually my_text_view could be anything) but is it even possible to have a layout with a single text view? link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 2):

Your `onBindViewHolder` already contains `holder` variable which holds references from your `onCreateViewHolder`. So, no need again to use `findViewById`. Official docs didn't do this, can be checked [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).